# Hessian of this function

Tags: calculus, functions, hessian-matrix

We have $$f(w) = \ln(1+\exp(-w^Tx))$$

Here, $w$ and $x$ are $d \times 1$

What's the hessian of this function?

I got gradient as $$\frac{-x\exp(-w^Tx)}{1+\exp(-w^Tx)}$$

then hessian as $$\frac{(1+\exp(-w^Tx))(x^2 \exp(-w^Tx)) - (-x\exp(-w^Tx))^2}{(1+\exp(-w^Tx))^2}$$

Is this correct? Why does it seem like the Hessian is a scalar? Also, I'm confused about the dimensions because how do we do $x^2$ if $x$ is $d \times 1$? Or should this be interpreted as $x^Tx$?

Comment: I think you mean that $w$ is $d\times 1$ as well, otherwise the product $w^Tx$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mnifldz you're right. edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful to think about this in terms of the matrix representation of the problem.  Your gradient looks fine, but think about what this should like like as a column vector.  If we take
$$
g(w) \;\; =\;\; -\frac{\exp(-w^Tx)}{1+\exp(-w^Tx)},
$$

Then the gradient
$$
\text{grad} f \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
g(w)x_1 \\
\vdots \\
g(w) x_d \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

When computing the Hessian, you construct a $d\times d$ matrix where in each entry you get

$$
\text{Hess}f \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_1} g(w)x_1 & \frac{\partial}{\partial w_2} g(w)x_1 & \ldots & \frac{\partial}{\partial w_d} g(w)x_1 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_1} g(w)x_2 & \frac{\partial}{\partial w_2} g(w)x_2 & \ldots & \frac{\partial}{\partial w_d} g(w)x_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_1} g(w)x_d & \frac{\partial}{\partial w_2} g(w)x_d & \ldots & \frac{\partial}{\partial w_d} g(w)x_d \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Nice, I think I understand it. Is my $x^2$ supposed to be $xx^T$? So is final Hessian $\frac{\exp(-w^Tx)}{(1+\exp(-w^Tx))^2}xx^T$

Comment: @sedrick Not likely.  You need to compute these derivative term-by-term and piece them together at the end when you can discern the matrix structure.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. I got that $\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}g(w)$ is just $\frac{\exp(-w^Tx)}{(1+\exp(-w^Tx))^2}x_i$. Does this make sense, or did I do something wrong in my calculations?

Comment: @sedrick In that case, then yes.  I couldn't tell how you got the expression, but piecing the matrix expression in the end is the correct way to do it.